# Pandas Dataframe - Add a new Column with value from another row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add a new column called `ordered_1day_ago` to my df.

DataFrame currently looks like this:

| itemID | orderedDate | qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/2/21 | 3 |
| 2 | 12/3/21 | 2 |
| 1 | 12/3/21 | 2 |
| 1 | 12/4/21 | 3 |

I want it to look like this:

| itemID | orderedDate | qty | ordered_1day_ago |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/2/21 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 12/3/21 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 12/3/21 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 12/4/21 | 3 | 2 |

`itemID` and `ordered date` must be used to insert the qty on the next orderedDate if it falls within one day, if it does not, then `ordered_1day_ago` is 0.

How can we use pandas for this?

Comment: Did you try the pandas series? check this document https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the complete solution:

```py
import pandas as pd

# a dict to create th dataframe
d = {
    'itemID':[1,2,1,1], 
    'orderedDate':['12/2/21', '12/3/21', '12/3/21', '12/4/21'],
    'qty':[3,2,2,3]
    }

# the old dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)

# some function to do what you want to based on rows
def some_function(row):
    # code goes here
    z = row['itemID'] + row['qty']
    return z

# add the new column given the function above
df['ordered_1day_ago'] = df.apply(some_function, axis=1)


# the new datafdrame with the extra column
print(df)
```

This is the original df:

```
   itemID orderedDate  qty
0       1     12/2/21    3
1       2     12/3/21    2
2       1     12/3/21    2
3       1     12/4/21    3
```

This is the new df with the added (example) column:

```
   itemID orderedDate  qty  ordered_1day_ago
0       1     12/2/21    3                 4
1       2     12/3/21    2                 4
2       1     12/3/21    2                 3
3       1     12/4/21    3                 4
```

You can amend the function to contain whatever criteria you wish such that the new column `ordered_1day_ago` contains the results that you wish.